# How to add space between Rows in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

main issue is i want to add some space between Rows and this Rows are children of `SingleChildScrollView`, my widget tree :

```
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          // first row with 3 column
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          // second row also with 3 column ans so on 
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
            //Row( third  row also with 3 column ans so on
              //Row( fourth  row also with 3 column ans so on
            // ....
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

i got the following out put :

[image: picture from emulator]

so how to add more space to the widget `SingleChildScrollView` , so to expect that `mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` put some space between the rows , or how simply add a space between rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things like `SizedBox` work great if you are happy with a fixed pixel gap. `Spacer` is another alternative, and is flexed, which may or may not be what you want, depending on what you have it nested under. If you prefer to work with relative sizes, I can also recommend `FractionallySizedBox`, which operates on a percentage of the area, and works great for responsive designs. If you wanted to have a 5% vertical gap, for example, you could express this as:

```
FractionallySizedBox(heightFactor: 0.05),
```

Answer (score 4):

try between the rows

```
SizedBox(height:20),
```

final code

```
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          // first row with 3 column
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height:20),
        Row(
          // second row also with 3 column ans so on 
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
            //Row( third  row also with 3 column ans so on
              //Row( fourth  row also with 3 column ans so on
            // ....
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `Padding` widget.

```
Row(...),
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
Row(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Spacer( ... . )
For me Padding is ok

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(...),
SizedBox(width:20).  // If want horizontal space use width  for vertical use height
Row(...)
```

you can use SizedBox b/w Rows

Comment: try it let me know there is multiple way doing this thing.