# Widget that takes up a fixed maximum of space, but shrinks to make room for other widgets inside Row

Tags: flutter

My Flutter UI has a Row widget with and arbitrary number Widgets in it. I would like to move all of those widgets over to the right by a fixed amount. But the caveat is, if the other widgets grow in width such that the available horizontal space is consumed, the spacing widget will relinquish its space.

The Spacer widget does not work for me, as it does not allow you to specify a fix maximum. It only allows a flex value, which is a function of the width of the other content in the row. I want this spacer to take up a fixed amount of space regardless of the width of the other content of the row (unless all the room is used up).

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing now - I want a column with the last widget typically a fixed distance from the bottom of the screen, but to reduce that if needed by other widgets above.

Answer (score -1):

Try using sizedBox or FractionallySizedBox as explained in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430801/8213343